# SVG child marker not showing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, markers

I'm having difficulties displaying markers. I use simple `line` object and here's what I tried:

- `marker-end` and `marker-start` properties - work as expected
- `marker-mid` - doesn't work
- using marker previously defined as child - doesn't work
- inline definition of a marker - doesn't work
- using css rules for markers - doesn't work

I've tried tweaking `overflow` and changing dimensions, but without any success. Also made sure that domain for element IDs from `<defs>` is correct.

```
<line
    x1={link.x1}
    y1={link.y1}
    x2={link.x2}
    y2={link.y2}
    className='node-link'
    strokeWidth="1"
    markerEnd="url(#diamond)"
>
    //<marker href="#diamond" position="50%"/>
    /*<marker
        // id="diamond"
        markerWidth="30"
        markerHeight="36"
        orient="auto"
        position="50%"
    >
        <rect
            height="15"
            width="15"
            className="node-link-marker"
        />
    </marker>*/
</line>
```

And the screenshot of DOM and style:

[image: screenshot of DOM]

At this point, I'm clueless, so any help is appreciated. Also note that it's being done in React, if it makes any difference, and that things work/break the same way in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Just made an JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/onw2br64/7/ that has the same behavior, so it's literally going against the specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#MarkerPatternProperty).

Comment: A line only has two vertices (each end of the line). There is no mid vertex. A marker cannot be a child of a line element. Your other points are unclear but you should read the SVG specification around makers to understand how they work.

Comment: I've tested with `path` as well. Was without success. Still doesn't explain why child element doesn't work.

Comment: A child element does not work because the SVG specification says that lines cannot have marker children. Similarly with all your other points I imagine.

Comment: Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hL8j37e6/) of Example 1 code from https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#issue5. And it doesn't work. Q.E.D.?

Comment: No browser supports https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers. It's in Working Draft